# How do I access orchestration endpoints in Cast Iron Live trial?

Tags: endpoint, orchestration, cast-iron

I've created a basic orchestration containing an HTTP Receive Request activity. I am able to deploy it to Cast Iron Live successfully, and it is running, but I have no idea how to access the endpoints.

The urls I have tried are https://eval-provide.castiron.com/env/Production/info, dropping the eval- prefix, and inserting the hexadecimal environment identifier. I get asked to authenticate for "Private Area", and occasionally for "WebID".

Can anyone tell me how I can find the correct endpoints so I can test my Orchestration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Cast Iron Live version 7.5.0.0 or higher (for both trail and production license castiron.ibmcloud.com)

then the URL will be

1. https://provide.castiron.ibmcloud.com/env/ENV_NAME/urlpath
   Here ENV_NAME will be the environment the orchestration is running. It can be Development or Production or the name/ID of the environment. 
   You need to provide your Live credentials as authorization header in this case.urlpath is the actual url provided for your ReST URL
2. https://provide.castiron.ibmcloud.com/envq/ENV_NAME/urlpath?ciUser=USER&ciPassword=PASSWORD
   Here ENV_NAME will be the environment the orchestration is running. It can be Development or Production or the name/ID of the environment.
   urlpath is the actual url provided for your ReST URL. Please note it is envq in the url.
   The Live credentials will be passed as query parameters in ciUser and ciPassword

Thanks
Sarath

Comment: Thank you Sarath. Is this officially documented somewhere, or does IBM hope that I'll eventually guess the URLs?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to invoke.

If you are using Cast Iron Live eval version 7.0.0.2 (eval-cloud2.castiron.com)

then the URL will be

1. https://eval-provide.castiron.com/env/ENV_NAME/urlpath
   Here ENV_NAME will be the environment the orchestration is running. It can be Development or Production or the name/ID of the environment. 
   You need to provide your Live credentials as authorization header in this case.urlpath is the actual url provided for your ReST URL
2. https://eval-provide.castiron.com/envq/ENV_NAME/urlpath?ciUser=USER&ciPassword=PASSWORD
   Here ENV_NAME will be the environment the orchestration is running. It can be Development or Production or the name/ID of the environment.
   urlpath is the actual url provided for your ReST URL. Please note it is envq in the url.
   The Live credentials will be passed as query parameters in ciUser and ciPassword

Thanks
Sarath